# how to get instance of usermanager in asp.net identity in custom controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How can I in my custom controller get an instance of ApplicationUserManager so that I can find a user by its id and then be able to update the user?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call:

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

inside any action you want to access the user manager. you also need to add following namespace also:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```